# Some code was lost after doing bzr commit --local, bzr pull, bzr commit

Tags: version-control, bazaar

A developer in my team has been using a branch bound to the server (IE, only using checkout, update, and commit), but also often uses the --local flag on commit and then commits to the server in a batch. She recently experienced a situation where she is missing some local commits, and can't find them in the repo OR her local code. She suspects that this is because she did a pull at some point in bettween local commits and server commits.

Neither of us are particularly experience with Bazaar -- What may have happened, and where can we look for this missing code? She is fairly certain that she never did anything destructive, and I am fairly certain that Bazaar would have asked her if it was going to do that. I vaguely remember that Bazaar has some notion of "hidden" repos/trees/whatever where it puts things before changing a bunch of code, from which someone might recover lost code, but I can't manage to google for what that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that the "'hidden' repos/trees/whatever" that I was referring to are "dead heads", viewed with `bzr heads`.

We found our dead head and merged it back in -- code saved!

```
$ bzr heads
$ # output shows various heads, with names like: revision-id: john@mycomputer-20100630175358-39qro1z5qdq2o9ay(dead)
$ bzr merge john@mycomputer-20100630175358-39qro1z5qdq2o9ay
```

Comment: Correct. You need bzrtools plugin installed to make `bzr heads --dead` working.

Answer (score 2):

If all else fails, you can try asking in the bazaar IRC channel.

[Go there now](http://webchat.freenode.net/)* and wander into the #bzr channel.  There are usually people there and they are usually helpful.

**That's freenode's web interface.  If you haven't used IRC before, you make up your own nickname, choose the #bzr channel, and no need to auth (as long as your nickname is unique).*

Comment: Thanks! I actually went there before here, but no one was around. That place is very helpful! Then it became morning in europe and people woke up and answered my question (which I will share after writing this).

Answer (score 0):

At any time you can do a

```
bzr status
```

and this will should you if there are any uncommitted changes, including merges that have not been committed.  This may help in determining where everything is at.  If you do a merge and you haven't followed it up with a commit (whether or not there were conflicts) then the result of the merge will remain uncommitted.

Doing a `bzr pull` shouldn't have wiped out any work - as I understand it, it should just fail if the local branch has uncommitted changes.

Comment: Yep, that's the usual workflow, but in this case status showed a clean working tree, even though my code was missing. `bzr heads` showed the dead head, from which I merged in my lost changes.